# iOS 8 Today View Extension with UITableViewController not showing footer (UIView)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview, ios8-today-widget

After wrestling with Core Data +  Extensions (sharing data) all day, I finally got it working, data is shared fine. Now, in my UITableViewController (inside my Today Extension), I'd like to have a constant footer view with a button to open the application, but I cannot get the UIView to display. I've tried doing it programmatically and via IB. Any ideas?

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
    UIButton *openButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(footerView.frame.origin.x, footerView.frame.origin.y, 300, 30)];
    [footerView addSubview:openButton];

    return footerView;
}
```

Comment: A little more information would be helpful. For example, I'm assuming you want the footer view always on screen and sitting beneath your table view?

Comment: @andrewbuilder exactly, I nice, helpful button below.

Comment: Use Interface builder / storyboard or construct views in code?

Comment: @andrewbuilder, as stated above, I have tried both. I've done this before in my previous applications, but for some odd reason, this doesn't want to work.

Comment: Are you setting a value for `self.preferredContentSize`? If so, what are you setting it to?

Comment: @TomHarrington I did, it was 0,0,320, array.count *44 + 44. The extra 44 for the footer view. I removed that line thinking something was wrong

Answer (score 0):

According to Apple, "It’s not a good idea to provide an “Open App” button" so I simply won't do it. According to the appropriate doc, its better to either a) code it to where if you tap on the widget, it opens your app, or b) have a general element to open your app in a 'focused' view.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/AppExtensions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH67-SW4